# index letter by letter with elasticsearch in rails app

Tags: elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5

does anyone knows what is the best way to index data letter by letter in elasticsearch . i have rails app witch i've use elasticsearch as search engine in my app. in my rails app i have alot of content that contain articles , in my implementation i can search through articles and return reult perfectly , i've multiple filter like ngram - edge gram - whitespace and ... . if user type exact full word every things fine and with my design i have some filter like ngram ,at this state i want to help user if he/she type one letter he/she could return some result i can handle this ponit with where command but i want to do it with elastics.
I`m looking through elastices tutorials and best practices but none of them can`t help me , at the best state if user type at least three or four letter elastices could return results .
I`m useing ngram filter
edge gram filter
regex
and ...
but none of them was useful.

Comment: Hi, If I understand well, you want something like auto complete function. Am I right?

Comment: Hi,Yeah you right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `suggest` query in elasticsearch as below:

```
{
 "suggest": {
 "auto-complete-suggest": {
 "prefix": "Your prefix text",
 "completion": {
  "size" : 5,
  "field": "text_completion"
 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and your mapping would be something like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text_completion": {
        "type": "completion",
        "analyzer": "Your analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks to your reply,it's solve my problem but now I have another problem , if i use (where command) i got every correct result but now for some query result are completly Irrelevant and for some query it return unuseable result

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry I can't understand your problem, completely. could you please provide me an example?

Comment: let me tell you more details , I have tag models witch contains some unique names , i expected when type b in postman all result begins with b , but except first result others are completly irrelevant

Comment: I checked again and all things was correct. I added multiple records and it just gave me back relevant results. What analyzer you are using for this?

Comment: this is ,y suggest api , [[def multi_match { "multi_match": {"query": @query, "fields": %w[name],"fuzziness":'auto' }}end]]       and this my mapping      [[{"mappings": {"tags":  "properties": {"name": {"type": "string }, }} }} ---- and i use edge-ngram analyzer

Comment: You have not used `completion type` in your mapping. For reaching some thing that you want you must use the mapping and query that I sent in the response. this is how it works

Comment: Hi, Could this code help you?? could you solve your problem??

Comment: Hi , Sorry to answer late , no it still have same problem even with changes you said

Comment: Could you please share your mapping and some of your test data with me?

Comment: of course ,  settings index: { number_of_shards: 1, number_of_replicas: 0 } do{ "mappings": {"tag":  "properties": { "text_completion": { "type": "completion", analyzer: 'edge_analyzer', }}}} , when i type b letter in post man i expect to see every tags whitch start with b letter bu i see result with other letter started and only first result start with b

Comment: for example when i type b letter expect to see ['blue','black','buddy'] but what i see is ['blue','red','green'] , i thinks it's about fuzziness else ican't understand what happend to my mapping

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will be thankful if you send your setting for edge_analyzer that you have used. I have test the code with standard analyzer and all things are fine.

Comment: yes ofcourse -- edge_filter = { type: 'edge_ngram', min_gram: 1, max_gram: 20, token_chars: ["letter", "digit"] }edge_analyzer = {type: 'edge_ngram', tokenizer: 'standard', filter: %w[edge_filter]}

Comment: I implemented your setting and analyzer again every thing is right. May I ask you to test this mapping completely exactly as it is:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223259/discussion-between-saeednasehi-and-hadi-varposhti).